# Not getting idea on how to run shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am running spark-submit command from shell and sending output to a file(/tmp/output). It has 3 varieties of statements ACCEPTED, RUNNING, FINISHED. If it is accepted nothing required. If it is RUNNING then i have to send mail. I have the logic to send mail. But running will be  seen multiple times in the tmp/output file. I'm not sure how many times. If i know i can put sleep till that time. When Finished statement occurs, i need to run query.

/tmp/output file is not static, it will be dynamic and append ACCEPTED, RUNNING multiple times. Below is the  example of /tmp/output file.

```
spark-submit --name sparktTest --deploy-mode cluster --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar 100 > /tmp/output

string=RUNNING

tail -n0 -F /tmp/output | \
while read LINE
do
if echo "$LINE" | grep "$string" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
then
echo "I am in while loop"
aws sns publish --message file:///tmp/url.txt
break
fi
done

stringnew=FINISHED
tail -f /tmp/output | \
while read LINE
do
if echo "$LINE" | grep "$stringnew" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
then
  aws sql query execute
        break
else
    echo "Script failed"
    break
fi
done
```

Running loop is executing successfully but immediately it is executing the script failed . It has to wait for FINISHED state in /tmp/output and then execute the sql query.

Comment: what  script you are running , what is the spark code you are trying to execute from shell . no one can answer based on theory that you wrote

Comment: Can you answer now.

Answer (score 0):

you need at least provide your script so someone will be able to help you ! So just add some more information first and then migh get some useful responses.

**Update**

well you want to check if a string exists in /tmp/output, so i assume its only one line that gets rewritten by the first command so a possible solution to wait for a FINISHED string looks like that

```
string=RUNNING

while cat /tmp/output | grep $string > /dev/null
do
echo "I am in while loop"

#do your code  that you want to do while the string is RUNNING
done
# the string in the /tmp/output changed to something else then RUNNING
echo "go on .."
```

this code just cat out the file to stdout then we grep for the string and dont print him out but we still do all the things in while loop. As soon as the string changes you leave the while loop and the scripts executes further

Comment: if i implement this code multiple times RUNNING will be seen in output file. Assume, 100 times running is seen in output file, i will send mail 100 times. I dont want that. For the first time RUNNING occurs i want to see the mail. Rest of the times it should ignore.

Comment: well then you need to go with tail  since you dont have a file with just one line. I looked like you override the file everytime in the first line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The script, as written will
* Wait for "RUNNING" line in the output
* Read the 10th line from the output
* If the line has 'FINISHED', do sql query, break
* Otherwise, show "failed", break

As per OP, the script should wait for the FINISHED. Something similar to the first loop

```
tail -F /tmp/output | \
while read LINE ; do
    if echo "$LINE" | grep "FINISHED" 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        echo "Running SQL ..."
        aws sql query execute
        break
    fi
done
```

Note that there are lot of assumption in this logic. In particular:

- There is no logic to capture aborted/failed jobs.  It is likely to hang forever on failed jobs.
- It assumes that there will be no gap in 'tailing' the temporary output file (which could cause a miss on the FINISHED message).
- Also, the script uses `/tmp/output` which could easily cause trouble if/when other scripts will use the same temporary file.

Comment: how to mention "script failed" in the above code snippet.

Comment: You need to provide sample output (from /tmp/output) for failures, if this is something you want to handle in the script.

Comment: In the /tmp/output file, FAILED will be seen only once.

Comment: Please post sample output with the FAILED into the question.